# Block links to CodeSandbox without providing the code

Tags: bug, questions, external-links

Links to code-sharing services are blocked when the person asks the question and doesn't put the code into the question.

It seems this is not the case with [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/):

See this question: [higher-order-components-react](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77548470/387194)

Comment: I'd like links to Github added to the list. There's far too many _"here's my code https://github.com/..."_ posts

Comment: Oh, and stackblitz.com

Comment: What about the 'fiddles'? - For example, [SQL Fiddle](https://sqlfiddle.com/), [JSFiddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSFiddle), [.NET Fiddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_online_source_code_playgrounds#Online_compiled_source_code_playgrounds), and [PhpFiddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_online_source_code_playgrounds#Online_web_client-side_source_code_playgrounds)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I think that it block jsFiddle and CodePen already. That's why I'm brining this up.